# User profile form, repeat new password and check if they match

Tags: user-profile, password

So there's the function to set a [new password](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/user-profile-form.html#password), but is there also the possibility to create a second password field to check if both new passwords matches and only then set the new password?

Comment: [This plugin](https://github.com/alecritson/Craft-Password-Confirm) would be a pretty straight forward rewrite for Craft 3.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Will rewrite this for Craft 3. Thanks as always Oli :)

Comment: Glad I could help!